# Using same itemID in a nested map in Java

Tags: java, collections

I am modeling these objects:
`Visitor' is a general object that has`Long visitorID;
`User` is a `Visitor` plus `enum UserType` plus `Date startedAt`
`Addressee` is a `User` plus `enum AddresseeType {TO, CC, BCC}`

Several `Addressee` instances can correspond to one `User`, so `extend` seems impractical. I store `User`s and `Addressee`s in `Map<Long, T extends Visitor>` and get objects by visitorID. It works, but the same `Long visitorID` is used in  several maps: each `AddresseeType`, `allUsers`, `allVisitors`.

What is the common way to store such nested objects without ID duplication?

---

Is it efficient or is there a better approach:

```
class Visitor{ Long visitorID; /*some other data*/}
class User{ Visitor visitor; UserType type; /*some other data*/}

class MyModel{ 
    Map<Long, Visitor> visitorIDtoVisitorMap;
    Map<Long, User> visitorIDtoUserMap;
    Map<AddresseeType, Map<Long,User>> recipientsGroupedByAddresseeTypeMap;
    /* more code */
}
```

Thhs code seems to violate DRY principle. For example `visitorIDtoUserMap` has the same `Long visitorID` both as a key and as a field variable inside of the value.

Comment: A common way to store something without ID duplication is to avoid ID duplication. You have to derive identity based on what uses are expected from the lookup dictionary. Otherwise, the question is unclear. Please specify, preferrably with using some code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please descripe what you looking for.

> Several Addressee instances can correspond to one User, so extend seems impractical.

That's true.

Creating a Object like E-Mail with a list of AddresseeType and Users may work.

Or Addressee has an refernece to a user object.

> each AddresseeType, allUsers, allVisitors

I do not understand what you mean.
But of cause you also can take multiple HashMap or HashSet:

```
  HashMap<Long, T extends Visitor> allVisitors;
  HashMap<Long, T extends Visitor> allUsers;
  HashSet<Long> addresseeTypeTO;
```

As a result you can easily check, if one id is used:

```
 allVisitors.containsKey(5465456);
 allUsers.containsKey(5465456);
 addresseeTypeTO.contains(5465456);  // getValue by using allVisitors.get(Long)
```

It is ok to use multiple maps and sets as the objects only exist one time and in each map or set only the long value and the address of the object is stored.